# Does the word 'Vinculation' exist?

Tags: is-it-a-word

My main language is portuguese and I'm stuyding English.

I've searched inside [Cambrigde Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) and didn't find it. But searching for the word itself, I find texts/articles using this word.

*- Word used as `bond/link` synonym. To express the idea of `attach` something to another.*

So I'm here to get help to learn if this is a real word or not.

ps:
There is the word in Portuguese/Spanish `Vincular / Vinculação`.

Comment: Well, it does now.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul 'Hypervinculation' isn't a word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It definitely is! But I'm not sure about its meaning.

Comment: 'Vinculate' is given in Wiktionary, [the] _English Wiktionary_ being the most comprehensive (as regards no. of headwords) English dictionary that exists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The fact that there is an entry (or lack of an entry) of anything in Wiktionary is hardly good evidence of its acceptability.

Comment: I remember 30 years ago, when internet chats were modem-driven and my Port<>Eng translation group kept fighting about precification and would not believe me when I said uh-huh.

Comment: What nobody is getting here is that the word in Portuguese and Spanish is quite frequent and in English vinculation is a horrible mistranslation. Yuck. Filho, você deveria prestar atenção às pessoas que sabem. Cada um dá um palpite, tudo errado.

Comment: @Mitch It's evidence that it's a known word or candidate. 'Wghftme' (if I can remember the answer Jasper Carrott came up with for a crossword clue correctly) (or even if I can't) isn't included. But you seem to have what FF calls 'a certain bias against Wiktionary here on ELU' [[see the ELL discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-much-should-i-trust-wiktionary)].

Answer (score 5):

It's in the O.E.D.

> **vinculation**: Insertion of a vincular vowel,

and

> **vincular**: Of a vowel: connective.

This is much more specific than its meaning seems to be in Spanish or Portuguese.

Comment: Weird... When I go to [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/)  and type `vinculation` it also says couldn't find the word.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: That's not the [O.E.D.](http://oed.com/) (which is 12 volumes in the dead tree edition and only accessible online if you have access through a library or other institution, or if you pay them largish sums of money). That's a much shorter Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: I will say something here. vincular and vinculação are used, for example, in contracts and legal language. Parties are said to be vinculados by this or that. And it means: bound, as in: this is a binding contract. In Spanish or Portuguese,  contrato vinculante, Also, if I say have no vínculos with this or that person, it means: I have no ties to them.  No bonds, if you will.

Comment: Yes.  This is a word where for obvious reasons English has the noun and verb 'link' (which is, after all a component of a chain).  Portuguese, obviously, starts from Latin.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Peter Shor's answer, I offer the following early instances of *vinculation* from English texts.

From "[Positivism in Theology](https://books.google.com/books?id=LQpHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA238&dq=%22vinculation%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj37-CghNTwAhVOs54KHULwCYgQ6AEwBnoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vinculation%22&f=false)," in *The Christian Examiner* (March 1866):

> When Positivism shall have supplied the missing links in Comtism, and completed the chain, then it ill have accomplished that last and sublimest achievement of the human mind, still, alas! in the remote future,—the enduring **vinculation** of "Science and Religion.”

From Benjamin Kennedy, [*The Public School Latin Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NI4CAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA19-IA4&dq=%22vinculation+or+insertion%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQlK3Ki9TwAhXGvJ4KHdl8DzIQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vinculation%20or%20insertion%22&f=false) (1871):

> (11) **Vinculation** or insertion of a Vincular Vowel (**i**, **u**, **e**). ... Thus e is inserted between **c-r**, **g-r**, **t-r**, **d-r**, **p-r**, **b-r**, **f-r**.

From "[Summary of Current Researches Relating to Zoology and Botany (Principally Invertebrata and Cryptogamia), Microscopy, &c., Including Original Communications from Fellows and Others](https://books.google.com/books?id=-ns4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA770&dq=%22vinculation%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi334D7hdTwAhUL6J4KHbkcAVs4ChDoATAAegQIBhAC#v=onepage&q=%22vinculation%22&f=false)," in *Journal of the Royal Microscopical Society* (October 1881):

> 2. ***Vinculation**-respiration*. This takes place in the case of the oil of oily seeds in the early stages of germination, the absorption of oxygen not being ccompanied by any evolution of carbonic acid.

From Frank Hill, "[Netherlands](https://books.google.com/books?id=IospAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA454&dq=%22vinculation%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi334D7hdTwAhUL6J4KHbkcAVs4ChDoATABegQIAhAC#v=onepage&q=%22vinculation%22&f=false)" (November 1, 1902), in *Commercial Relations of the United States with Foreign Countries During the Year 1902* (1903):

> Since the **vinculation** between the Postal Savings Bank of the Netherlands and Belgium is so close, I think it advisable to add the official statistics of the Belgium Government Savings Bank as transmitted to the Department of State by Consul Roosevelt, of Brussels, April 24, 1901.

These four instances arise in the context of four different disciplines: philosophy, linguistics, botany, and economics. Of the four, the one in which the largest number of subsequent instances appear is economics—and more specifically, economic regulations. For example, in William Penfield, "[Oral Argument [in the case of the United States vs. the Republic of Salvador] Before the Arbitrators, Sir Henry Strong, Chief Justice of Canada, The Honorable Don M. Dickinson, of Michigan, and Dr. Rosa Pacas, of Salvador, Tuesday, April 15, 1902](https://books.google.com/books?id=PsTlAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22vinculation%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj37-CghNTwAhVOs54KHULwCYgQ6AEwAXoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vinculation%22&f=false)" (1902):

> I come now to the decree of May 13, and I would invite the attention of the honorable arbitrators to the concatenation or **vinculation** of these events. The mind of the Government was manifested in the suit of June 14, 1898, brought by the Solicitor of the Treasury to annul and get rid of this concession.
>
> ...
>
> I want to read it [the decree of May 13, 1899], and, with the permission of the honorable arbitrators, I want to comment upon that; but I want to establish this **vinculation** of the circumstances, showing the intent of the Executive Government.

The specific type of connection that each writer or speaker intended for *vinculation* to convey in these different settings is unclear at this historical distance, but it seems fairly clear that the word did not broadly succeed in supplanting more familiar words such as *linkage*, *connection*, and *attachment* as a term of art in any of these fields.

Nevertheless, *vinculation* continues to appear in English texts (predominantly in ones related to Latin America, and perhaps most often in contexts where the author is dealing with a Spanish or Portuguese cognate) frequently enough to register as an Ngram graph. The following chart tracks the frequency of occurrence of *vinculation* in English texts for the period from 1850 to 2019:

[image]

Comment: How funny. That Netherlands thing is completely **wrong**. I wonder if that was translated. The point is that it does not really exist in English as vinculación/ção exists in Spanish and Portuguese, to mean the binding of a contract on someone. the ties or bonds someone has with another.

Comment: Can you give any indication about the relative frequency of 'vinculation' to other English words? The NGram only shows the change in frequency all by itself. Which [OED frequency band](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-frequency/) does it lie in?

Comment: If you read those texts, most seem to be translations. All those ngram hits are translation errors. Ha ha ha.

Comment: All of the instances that I quote in my answer are by British or U.S. speakers or authors; none of are translations. Some of the more recent ones in Google Books search results undoubtedly are translations, but others appear in such contexts as [testimony by U.S. officials](https://books.google.com/books?id=peAjAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA271&dq=%22vinculation%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO6JP75dTwAhUDKDQIHVnJDTw4ChDoATABegQIBRAC#v=onepage&q=%22vinculation%22&f=false) and are therefore in use by native English speakers. ...

Comment: ... A spot check of the [Ngram matches](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vinculation&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvinculation%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvinculation%3B%2Cc0) reveals some—but not a huge number of—OCR errors in the early matches. It is certainly possible to find false positives and (potentially) poor translations in the search results, but there are also enough matches that don't fall into either of those categories to render the assertion that there is no such word as _vinculation_ in English highly dubious. ...

Comment: ... That doesn't mean, however, that the word is in widespread, general use (I have never encountered it in the wild) or that it is in even even occasional use outside certain specialty areas such as international law.

Comment: That Canadian lawyer is arguing about a Salvadoran law decree, which we cannot see. So, he has **in fact** made a de facto, Latinate translation from Spanish as the word does not exist in legal English, only Spanish English.

Answer (score -2):

It’s definitely a word!
To vinculate means to tie or bind.
To have vinculated means to have tied or bound something in the past tense.
So vinculation means the tying or binding of something.

Example sentence: Did you see the vinculation of the ropes  inside?

Please note this word is considered rare and I have never heard it used before.

Comment: What is the source for the definition?

Comment: No, vincular is to tie something to someone or something. To have a bond with someone or something. vinculate calls for the **buzzer**.